# Can I add a date value dynamically into a part of a text in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

If it is possible, I want to add current date value into a text.
When I run the following code, SQLite stores only date value like "2015.01.01" to description field instead of "The date is 2015.01.01 right now".

I couldn't find any article relevant my issue on the sqlite.org and the internet.

Can I do this?

```
INSERT INTO myTable
   (rowid, description)
VALUES
   (1, "The date is " + (date('now')) + " right now" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not about Date it was how to concatenate String Sqlite uses `||` operator to concatenate strings so following is the solution I would suggest;

```
INSERT INTO test
   (rowid, description)
VALUES
   ( 1, "The date is "|| date('now')  ||" right now"   )
```

see more details about sqlite [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. This works;

```
INSERT INTO myTable
   (rowid, description)
VALUES
   ( 1, replace( "The date is ZZ right now", "ZZ", date('now') )   )
```

**Result;**

```
                   myTable
---------------------------------------------
rowid |   description 
---------------------------------------------
1     |   The date is 2014-12-12 right now
```